# I can't change the iframe dimensions in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: iframe, internet-explorer-9

http://www.chungstudio.com/the_city_stars/#blog

i have a tumblr blog in an iframe that appears normally in firefox, chrome, safari, and even internet explorer 10, but with internet explorer 9, i can't change the dimensions of the iframe.

is there an alternative mark-up for iframes in ie9?

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using css to set it to 100%;
CSS is interpreted differently across different browsers - try using a CSS-reset or removing the padding/margins.

in main.css:

```
.blog iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

try adding the lines:

```
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
```

(or setting them to your preferred spacing).  Browsers work better to the rules if you define the behaviour you want them to have instead of relying on defaults.

I try not to get caught up too much in cross-browser CSS uniformity; people choose browsers for different reasons - one of which is how it interprets default values.

Of course if you didn't want 100%...these are the lines to modify.